# Ошибка миграции There is already an object named 'Permission' in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, миграция

Не понимаю, постоянно ловлю ошибки например

> There is already an object named 'Permission' in the database.

из за чего постоянно дропаю бд и запускаю миграцию с нуля, что сводит меня с ума. Таблица уже существует в БД `Permission` я добавляю новое поле, которое `foreignkey`
Модели:

```
public class Permission
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}  

public class PermissionRole
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RoleFK")]
    public ICollection<MyIdentityRole> Roles { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PermissionFK")]
    public ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
}

public class MyIdentityRole : IdentityRole
{
    public string AltName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MyIdentityRoleFK")]
    public Permission Permission { get; set; }

    public MyIdentityRole() : base() { }
    public MyIdentityRole(string name, string altName)
   : base(name)
    {
        AltName = altName;
    }
}
```

Все таблицы согласно моделей уже по средством предыдущих миграций были созданы в БД. Сейчас я создал модель `PermissionRole` и добавил два внешних ключа. По логике он должен создать таблицу(`PermissionRole`) и добавить по столбцу в существующие таблицы, но он почему то пытаться создать их снова вместо `alter table` делает `create` подскажите, что я делаю не так?(Я так уже нажарился, что ручками 100 раз бы уже всю структуру БД сделал бы)

Comment: ну а у вас в БД уже есть этот `Permission`  ?

Comment: @tym32167 да. Я просто думал, что инструмент миграции сам должен переживать есть она там или нет. Поэтому сделал умозаключение что я где то делаю ошибку

Comment: там всё сложнее немного. Если я верно помню, то при создании миграции EF смотрит на снапшот, который в проекте с контекстом лежит, а не на БД